# Am I committing a crime with the ftplib library?

Tags: python, ftplib

With these three lines of Python code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp=FTP("ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov")
ftp.login()
```

I successfully login to the FTP server of NOAA (National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration), but I get this message printed as output:

> '230-****** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING
>   ******** This is a United States Department of Commerce computer     **** system, which may be accessed and used only for             **** official Government business by authorized personnel.       ** ** Unauthorized access or use of this computer system may      **** subject violators to criminal, civil, and/or administrative **** action.  All information on this computer system may be     **** intercepted, recorded, read, copied, and disclosed by and   **\n ** to authorized personnel for official purposes, including    **** criminal investigations.  Access or use of this computer    **** system by any person, whether authorized or unauthorized,   **** constitutes consent to these terms.                         **\n ****** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ** WARNING ******\n230 Anonymous access granted, restrictions apply'

Is this saying that I am not allowed to download files from that FTP server, unless I am an authorized personnel? Or is it just a warning that I should not try to somehow access and modify the server content?
Sorry if I am not understanding it correctly, but that may be because I am not from the US, and I am not sure how cyber crime works in there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is requesting legal advice, not programming help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine. NOAA FTP servers are open for general use, but there are a few rules around using scripts that you should take a look at.

http://www.nws.noaa.gov/tg/general.php

http://www.nws.noaa.gov/tg/dataprod.php